# CSV Imported with column merged

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to upload a CSV file into Python.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
from pandas.io import sql

BANK_FULL = pd.read_csv('../csv/bank-full.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
print(BANK_FULL.columns)
```

Output:

```
Index(['age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"'], dtype='object')
```

[image: example]

This ends up showing all into 1 column. I know right now they are double-quoted, therefore shown as 1 column. How can I change the double quote into normal quote, so that my columns will show nicely?

Example of text from the CSV file:

> age job marital education default balance housing loan contact day
> month duration campaign pdays previous poutcome y
>
> 58 management married tertiary no 2143 yes no unknown 5 may 261 1 -1 0
> unknown no
>
> 44 technician single secondary no 29 yes no unknown 5 may 151 1 -1 0
> unknown no
>
> 33 entrepreneur married secondary no 2 yes yes unknown 5 may 76 1 -1 0
> unknown no

Comment: Did you forget to show the code you've developed?

Comment: How did you read the file? Post a working example including a few lines of the CSV. We want to know if it has a header and what it is using as column separators. Right now you haven't shown us either the code or the data... how are we to guess?

Comment: I am very new to this forum,I am learning how to post it here. very new to python as well. sorry, let me figure out how to post it here

Comment: Put that into the question. Then use the `{}` button to make it into a code block. That makes it much easier to read.

Comment: thank you so much for guiding @tdelaney have updated the question

Comment: It looks like the file is semicolon separated, not comma. Post the first few lines as text, then there is something to experiment with.

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure what do you mean by posting first few lines as text

Comment: Just copy the first 4 lines from bank-full.csv and paste them here. Not as an image or screen shot or something, just paste the text into the question. Turn it into a code block for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the delimiter as semicolon. Your code should be like:

```py
import pandas as pd

BANK_FULL = pd.read_csv('../csv/bank-full.csv', encoding='utf-8', delimiter=";")
print(BANK_FULL.columns)
```

which results in:

```py
Index(['age', 'job', 'marital', 'education', 'default', 'balance', 'housing',
       'loan', 'contact', 'day', 'month', 'duration', 'campaign', 'pdays',
       'previous', 'poutcome', 'y'],
      dtype='object')
```